# how to send parameter in Url.RouteUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have **select** with **option** and **button**. When i press button, i do that function:

```
function selectBillingAddress() {
                        var ca = $('#billing-address-select').find(":selected").val();
                    setLocation('@Html.Raw(Url.RouteUrl("CheckoutSelectBillingAddress", new {addressId = , shipToSameAddress = "true"}))');
                }
```

i need to send "var ca" to "addressId", but i cant... i dont know enough javascript and jquery. thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You cannot. `Url.RouteUrl()` is razor (server side) code that is executed in the server before the view is sent to the browser. `ca` is a javascript variable that is executed on the client

Comment: You can create the 'base' url using the `RouteUrl` and then modify its value in the script.

Comment: Thank you for answer @StephenMuecke. i find this way: `var selecteAddressId = $('#billing-address-select').find(":selected").val();
                            var route = '@Url.RouteUrl("CheckoutSelectBillingAddress", new {addressId = "selecteAddressId"})';</code>
                            route = route.replace("selecteAddressId", selecteAddressId);
                            setLocation(route);`